# How to make a button group appear above another <div>?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a container in which there is a vertical scrollable carousel of Images.

[image]

I wanted a button group which acted as tabs over these images something like this.

[image]

This is the code for the button group and it's result.

```
<template>
<div class="row">
 <div class="gallery-container">
  <div class="template-tabs-container">
   <v-btn-toggle tile color="secondary" group>
    <v-btn>All </v-btn>
    <v-btn>Private</v-btn>
    <v-btn>Shirt</v-btn>
    <v-btn>Suit</v-btn>
   </v-btn-toggle>
  </div>
  <div v-for="tem in allTemplates" v-bind:key="tem.id" class="gallery-item item-template">
   <img :src=tem.thumbnailLink height="150" width="105">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>

</script>
<style>
.row {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
}

.gallery-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 65%;
    /* display: none; */
    /* display: block; */
}

.gallery-templates {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px; 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.gallery-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
</style>
```

[image: img]

How can I make these buttons appear above these images as tabs like in the images above?

Comment: can you add your css for the page? Then we can look why it is displayed there and not at the correct position

Comment: @Warden330 Added the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet with basic html / CSS as an example:

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    /*height + width only set for display in snippet, you dont need that*/
    height: 250px;
    width: 100vw;
}

/*main container*/
.gallery-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 65%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
/*button container needs the same width as Image container and needs to be row*/
.buttons {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
/*buttons need fixed width, same as images*/
.buttons button {
  width: 25%;
}
/*image container needs the same width as button container and needs to be row*/
.images {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
/*Images need fixed width, same as buttons*/
.images img {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <!--Main Container-->
 <div class="gallery-container">
  <div class="template-tabs-container">
  <!--Container for buttons-->
   <div class="buttons" tile color="secondary" group>
    <button>button1 </button>
    <button>button2 </button>
    <button>button3 </button>
    <button>button4 </button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!--Container for images-->
  <div class="images">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/15/06/02/leaves-5572789_960_720.jpg">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/15/06/02/leaves-5572789_960_720.jpg">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/15/06/02/leaves-5572789_960_720.jpg">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/15/06/02/leaves-5572789_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So you basically want to make the overall gallery-container a flex-column so the container for the button and the container for the images get displayed above each other. Then you need to make sure that the buttons are displayed as a row and the row has the same width as the image-row. What i have not included as code here is that you need to give the individual buttons a class or just style them directly, make sure that the buttons have the same individual width as the individual images. Then they should be on top of each other:

```
 .gallery-container {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 65%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    /*buttons*/
    .template-tabs-container {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    /*images*/
    .gallery-templates {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px; 
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it will be more helpful if you can explain with an example. Thank You.

Comment: added an example :)